# About drop table in Slave instance Mysql RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, replication

Good night, I have a need that consists of deleting some tables that are already in exception (parameter of not replicating tables from master to slave)
Because they only take up space, since they don't have updated data.

How to proceed?
MySQL 5.7
Amazon's RDS

Comment: Did you try just doing `DROP TABLE` on the slave?

Comment: You might consider launching a new replica instance, and then terminate the broken one.

Comment: ok,   @ceejayoz nops, because I still keep the old data in slave and keep new data in master ( transactional ).